# Asynchronous task processor

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous

I am developing an asynchronous task processor. I need high-performance processor, so synchronization primitives used should be as low-level as possible. The processor should hold a thread that sleeps when there are no tasks, and wakes up when tasks appear. Tasks processing and tasks adding should be performed in different threads.

I tried implementation with `AutoResetEvent`, but it has race condition:

```
public class Processor
{
    ConcurrentQueue<Action> _workItemQueue = new ConcurrentQueue<Action>();
    AutoResetEvent _newWorkItemAutoResetEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    private bool _disposed;
    Thread _thread;

    public void Do(Action action)
    {
        _workItemQueue.Enqueue(action);
        _newWorkItemAutoResetEvent.Set();
    }

    public Processor()
    {
        _workerThread = new Thread(() =>
        {
            while (!_disposed)
            {
                _newWorkItemAutoResetEvent.WaitOne(); // 
                while (_workItemQueue.TryDequeue(out Action action))
                {
                    action();
                }
                // at this "bad" moment another thread calls Do method. 
                // New action has been enqueued, but when we call
                // _newWorkIteManualAutoEvent.WaitOne() we fall asleep.
            }
        });
        _thread.Start();
    }
}
```

Then I tried implementation with `ManualResetEvent`:

```
public class Processor
{
    ConcurrentQueue<Action> _workItemQueue = new ConcurrentQueue<Action>();
    ManualResetEventSlim _newWorkItemManualResetEvent = new ManualResetEventSlim(false);
    private bool _disposed;
    Thread _thread;

    public void Do(Action action)
    {
        _workItemQueue.Enqueue(action);
        _newWorkItemManualResetEvent.Set();
    }

    public Processor()
    {
        _workerThread = new Thread(() =>
        {
            while (!_disposed)
            {
                _newWorkItemManualResetEvent.WaitOne();
                _newWorkItemManualResetEvent.Reset();

                while (_workItemQueue.TryDequeue(out Action action))
                {
                    action();
                }
            }
        });
        _thread.Start();
    }
}
```

I don't see any race conditions in implementation with `ManualResetEvent`.

QUESTION: Am I right? Or I need another synchronization primitive? I'm thinking of Count**up**Event (reverse [`CountdownEvent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.countdownevent)). It is signaled when its count greater than zero and isn't signaled when its count equals to zero. Count**up**Event's count corresponds to count of tasks to be executed.

Comment: The questions about working implementation which you want to improve have to be asked on [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: "I need high-performance processor, so synchronization primitives used should be as low-level as possible" - if performance mattered _that_ badly you wouldn't be using C#.NET at all because of delays introduced by JIT compilation and GC. The performance overheads of .NET's built-in async and thread-pool features are minimal, and they're tried-and-tested. Your own code is actually very inefficient because you're blindly creating new threads and threads are expensive on Windows - not to mention how you're and then blocking those threads with `WaitOne()`. Why aren't you using the thread-pool?

Comment: This seems to be a "concurrent task processor" and not a "asynchronous task processor".

Comment: @Dai, I need C# implementation only, as high perfomance as possible. In my implementation one processor creates only one thread. I do not plan create many of processors.

Comment: @Enigmativity, I called the processor asynchronous, as it can perform tasks asynchronously: when Do method call, action passed is not executed at once, and gets in queue and is executed in another thread later when the turn comes. Tasks are performed in turn, not simultaneously, there is no concurrency.

Comment: The problem with calling the processor "asynchronous" is that it may create wrong expectations. Nowadays the word "asynchronous" is heavily associated with the [Task-based asynchronous pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/task-based-asynchronous-pattern-tap). People will expect from the processor to return `Task` objects, or accept `Func<Task>` delegates, or both.

Answer (score 1):

The handy [BlockingCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/thread-safe/blockingcollection-overview?view=netframework-4.8) will handle most of this for you.

Something like:

```
public sealed class Processor : IDisposable
{
    //set a max queue depth to provide back pressure to the request rate
    BlockingCollection<Action> _workItemQueue = new BlockingCollection<Action>(32);
    private bool _disposed = false;
    private Thread _workerThread;
    private CancellationTokenSource _cancelTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

    public void Do(Action action)
    {
        _workItemQueue.Add(action);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (!_disposed)
        {
            _workItemQueue.CompleteAdding();
            _cancelTokenSource.Cancel();
            _disposed = true;
        }
    }

    public Processor()
    {
        _workerThread = new Thread(() =>
        {
            while (!_workItemQueue.IsCompleted)
            {
                if (_workItemQueue.TryTake(out Action action, 1000*2,_cancelTokenSource.Token))
                {
                    action();
                }
            }

        });

        _workerThread.Start();
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) _workerThread will always spin when no tasks and consume CPU resources. Is not it?

2) Are you sure that your implementation with  BlockingCollection will be faster than my implementation with ManualResetEvent?

Comment: It's not supposed to be faster.  It's supposed to be correcter :).  Ie simpler, and less prone to difficult-to-find concurrency issues.  And breaking out of a wait every second or two to do bookkeeping has a trivial CPU cost.  2000ms is an eternity to a CPU.

Comment: Instead of using the `IsCompleted`+`TryTake` combo, a better way to enumerate the collection is by using the [`GetConsumingEnumerable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1.getconsumingenumerable).

Comment: That's very good, especially when combo'd with Parallel.Foreach, but I like TryTake for the same reason @IgorBuchelnikov objected to.  You can timeout the wait periodically and update telemetry, logging, and prove that the thread isn't blocked or spinning on one of the work items.

Comment: That's a valid argument. A small drawback of using `IsCompleted`+`TryTake` is that the `cancellationToken` slot is now used for the internal housekeeping of the processor, and if you want to support cancellation by the caller you'll have to create a linked CTS. Which admittedly is not a big deal.